# When we give a fixed width to an element why it is taking less that that fixed width when its nearby content is changing in case of display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a label and button, and I have given a fixed width to the button, if label text is less, it is taking given width but when label text increased button is taking less width.

Why is it happening ?

I didn't gave any width to label.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label>Some text now this text is incrasinf </label>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  border: solid green;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

label {
    border: solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow:1;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

When label text is small button is taking 100px as expected.

[image]

When the label text increased button is taking less than 100px (unexpected for me)

[image]

Codepen Link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGmMpd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the button - the *default* is `flex-shrink: 1` and so according to the change in content *flex items* can *shrink*.

See demo below:

```css
div {
  border: solid green;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

label {
  border: solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Some text now this text is incrasinf </label>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```